# How do I add a switch to server startup in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, quartz-scheduler, oc4j

I'm using eclipse to manage my server instance, I'm wondering if it's possible to add other options/switches to the command that starts the server. Let me know if there's a way, or if I'm taking the wrong approach...

This is the error I'm getting in my application (using Quartz):

> `Not in an application scope - start OC4J with the -userThreads switch if using user-created threads`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm pretty sure it's not easy to do, I read something on [the eclipse newslist](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg14958.html) about modifying one of the driver config files:

> Edit appopriate oracle.x.x.x.x.serverdef file in 
>   
> <eclipse>\plugins\org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.oc4j_1.5.100.v20070608\servers 
>   
> folder; tag <programArguments> 
>   
> (<programArguments>-userThreads</programArguments>)
>   You might be required to redefine the server instance.

I had some difficulty implementing this so I just ran (from the command line):

> java -jar oc4j.jar -userThreads

which I suppose is the way that I'm supposed to do it anyway... >_<